# Multiple Knockout ViewModels

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to bind multiple ViewModels to one view. 
Now after this works i got a problem with a function.
Somehow i have to click a function twice to get to the other ViewModel

```
 <div data-bind= "visible: showStartStamp">
    <input type="button" value="START" name="StartStamp"  data-bind="click: startTimestamp"/>
  </div>
  <div data-bind= "visible: showStopStamp">
    <input type="button" value="STOP" name="StopStamp"  data-bind="click: stopTimestamp"/>
  </div>
```

The knockout Function looks like this

```
this.showStart = function () {
    masterViewModel.projectStartVM(new ProjectStartVM());
    masterViewModel.detailsVM(null);
};
```

And another thing is, that the Knokockout-Binding in the ProjectStartVM doesn't work correctly!

Here is a js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4A87x/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code works exception there are no `startTimestamp` and `stopTimestamp` functions defined in `ProjectStartVM`. Also I have fixed several minor issue, here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4A87x/11/

Comment: now i have another problem!

i tried to include this jsfiddle in my ASP.NET MVC4 Page...
Now i tried to make a fiddle again and it still is not working :/ 
Could you please take a look at this fiddle? 
http://jsfiddle.net/4A87x/15/

Comment: You renamed detailsVM to startVM in masterViewModel but not in showDetails function. Here is fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4A87x/16/ . Be more attentive

Comment: somehow this worked in jsFiddle, but not in ASP.NET 
I have now idea what I've done wrong...